# How to solve "Object Reference" error in Azure Function argument

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm relatively new to Azure Functions and C#, and I've been encountering an issue that's been puzzling me. I hope you can help me out.

I have an Azure Function written in C#, and I'm trying to trigger it with a Service Bus message. However, I'm getting the following error from this line of code

```
public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("registrationsconfirmationemails", Connection = _conf.GetSection("azureservicebus").Value] string myQueueItem)
```

Error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Function2._conf'

Code:

```
public class Function2
{
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        public IConfiguration _conf { get; set; }

        public Function2(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function2>();
            _conf = this.GetConf();
        }

        [Function("Function2")]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("registrationsconfirmationemails", Connection = _conf.GetSection("azureservicebus").Value] string myQueueItem)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(myQueueItem);
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
        }

        private IConfiguration GetConf()
        {
            // get config
        }
}
```

Comment: Attribute arguments have to be constants - you can't execute a method, whether it's static or not...

Answer (score 0):

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Function2._conf'

I do agree with @Jon Skeet, This error occurs when you provide non static arguments, you require a constant in that place .

So, you cannot call a method over here and you need to use something like this:

```
public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "connec")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
```

[image]

Then in **`local.settings.json`** you need to add that **`connec`** to connect azure function to service bus:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "connec": "Endpoint=sb://rithwik.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=o="
  }
}
```

**`Output:`**

When you send a message :

[image]

The function triggers:

[image]